# randi generating the same result on a cluster

Tags: matlab, slurm

The following code should generate two random letters:

```
lett_array = ['abcdefghijklmnobqrstuvwxyz'];
SaveStr.random = ['_',lett_array(randi(26)),lett_array(randi(26))];
```

It works exactly as expected on my local machine (adds random letters to a save file name to maintain uniqueness).

However on a cluster using slurm scheduling, I get back well over 200 results that ALL CALCULATE THE SAME PAIR OF LETTERS (runs initiate within 15 mins of each other; end over the span of 45 minutes).

This seems... weird.  I could probably force reasonable behaviour using

```
rng('shuffle');
lett_array = ['abcdefghijklmnobqrstuvwxyz'];
SaveStr.random = ['_',lett_array(randi(26)),lett_array(randi(26))];
```

but I don't understand how I'm having the problem in the first place.

Thoughts?  Seems a big problem that matlab doesn't get reliably random numbers on linux clusters.

Comment: If you need to generate an `unique (random)` filename, you can consider a combination of [tempname](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tempname.html) and [fileparts](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html): `[~,filename,~] = fileparts(tempname)`

Comment: MATLAB always initializes it's random number generator the same way when starting up. This is documented behavior. If you need separate MATLAB sessions producing different random sequences, you need to shuffle the generator.

Comment: Thanks!  It is badly documented though.  I should not have to go multiple pages into help documentation to find a hint in the middle of the page that suggests that MATALB initialises rng with a consistent seed.  That should be bold top-of-page statement if ever there was one.  What kind of savage doesn't seed an rng function with the wall clock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the `rng` (random number generator) [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html):

> `rng('default')` puts the settings of the random number generator used by `rand`, `randi`, and `randn` to their default values. This way, the same random numbers are produced **as if you restarted MATLAB**.
>
> The default settings are the Mersenne Twister with seed 0.

So you're getting the same values because the cluster nodes each act on a new instance on MATLAB, which uses `rng('default')` as the initialisation for the random number generator.

Using `rng shuffle` or `rng('shuffle')` is the correct thing to do if you want independent randomness on the cluster nodes.

---

You might also be interested to know about the `char` function. Since your `let_array` array is equivalent to ASCII `97:122`, you can simply forget the letters array and do a single call to `randi` like so:

```
 SaveStr.random = ['_', char(randi([97,122], 1, 2))];
```